# How to build an address book for Ethereum addresses?

Tags: solidity, addresses, mapping, string

I would like a simple address book referencing a user name to an ethereum address like,

```
mapping (string => address) addressOf;
```

Unfortunately I can't access that mapping as a public call, as strings are dynamically-sized.

Is there any existing solution or work around, to access a string key mapping without .sendTransaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bytes32 like this:

```
contract NameRegistry {
    mapping(bytes32 => address) addressBook;

    function set(string a, address b){
        addressBook[sha3(a)] = b;
    }

    function get(string a) constant returns(address){
        return addressBook[sha3(a)];
    }
}
```